# MariaDB "insert into" multiple rows with multiple subqueries

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Trying to insert a new row for each of the entries of a table.

```
INSERT INTO `serviceProducts`(`model_id`, `url_name`, `priority`, `status`, `info`, `image_link`, `mobilephone`, `service`, `time`, `price`) 
SELECT id FROM models,
CONCAT(SELECT url_name FROM models,"-felsoekning"),
10,
1,
"",
"",
(SELECT name FROM models),
"Felsökning",
"",
399
```

I want to add a new "service" entry for each of the models present. Therefore I need to select all model ids as well as their url-friendly names and normal names. This query returns an error near (SELECT name FROM models).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
INSERT INTO `serviceProducts`(`model_id`, `url_name`, `priority`, `status`, `info`, `image_link`, `mobilephone`, `service`, `time`, `price`) 
SELECT id,
CONCAT(url_name, "-felsoekning"),
10,
1,
"",
"",
name,
"Felsökning",
"",
399
from models;
```

Comment: Of course the answer is always the simplest thing :). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't use subqueries in the `SELECT`. Just use a single `SELECT` that merges the constants with the columns from the other table.

```
INSERT INTO `serviceProducts`(`model_id`, `url_name`, `priority`, `status`, `info`, `image_link`, `mobilephone`, `service`, `time`, `price`) 
SELECT id, CONCAT(url_name,"-felsoekning"), 10, 1, "", "", name, "Felsökning", "", 399
FROM models
```

Comment: I actually didn't know that. Thanks